# What happens to the item level/heat when used to craft a new item?

Tags: spiral-knights

The wiki does not address that problem.

I know some items require an item "of level X or above", but beside that, the level is just lost, or a % is transferred to the new item, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All newly crafted items start at level 1. So yeah, the level and heat on any weapons needed in the crafting is lost. You can keep your unique variants though, or try for new ones.

Comment: You mean, if there aren't unique variants, I still have a chance to get one?

Comment: @Lo'oris - correct.